# buffer overflow literature for C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, buffer-overflow

does someone know good literature for C/C++?
language: german/english

thanks

Comment: have you heard of the internet? Try it, it works great!

Comment: @Mitch: Err... didn't the OP need to use the internet to ask the question?

Comment: @Billy ONeal: was that humor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the classic treatsie ...

[Smashing The Stack For Fun And Profit](http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html)l

Answer (score 2):

[This one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321335724) has an entire chapter on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

This [book from Jon Erickson](http://books.google.es/books?id=P8ijosP6ti4C&lpg=PP1&ots=6Q71WskfGu&dq=hacking%20jon%20erickson&hl=en&pg=PA22#v=onepage&q&f=false):

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) has a great intro with pointers on what to read next.

Answer (score 0):

[The Shellcoder's Handbook: Discovering and Exploiting Security Holes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/047008023X)